# Does Ireland's Dáil have an unusually high number of independents, compared to other European legislatures?

Tags: europe, comparative-politics, republic-of-ireland, legislature, independent-politicians

I noticed that the 4th largest "party" in the current Dáil are independents with 19/160 seats. Is this proportion high (or not) in a broader European perspective in national legislatures?

Comment: Is there more to this question than "is number X higher or lower than number Y"? Also depends what you'd consider a party/independent TD. e.g. what are the members of "Independents 4 Change" considered?

Comment: The seat count on RTE considers I4C to be "other" and not independent.  I'm not going to research other European countries but one reason there is a significant number of independents in Ireland is the PR system that means popular candidates can get elected even if they are not the most popular.  Another factor is the number of people who used to be in a party, quit or were kicked out, but still mostly vote their ex-party line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Below is a boxplot which shows the current (March 2020) proportion of independent members of each house of each national parliament in the European Union. From this, we can identify outliers in a statistical sense - any chamber that has more than ~6% of its membership represented by independent candidates should be considered an outlier.

[image]

The chambers that match these criteria in descending order are both chambers of the Irish Parliament; the Senead and the Dáil, the Romanian Senate, the Croatian Parliament, and the Latvian Saeima. The full figures used can be found below, and were pulled from Wikipedia. Note that I have excluded the Slovenian National Council, as the membership represents interest groups in the country and is not directly elected, it doesn't make sense to include it in this data.

Full data used:

| Country | House | Members | Independents | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ireland | Seanad | 60 | 15 | 25.00% |
| Ireland | Dáil | 160 | 19 | 11.88% |
| Romania | Senate | 136 | 16 | 11.76% |
| Croatia | Parliament | 151 | 16 | 10.60% |
| Latvia | Saeima | 100 | 9 | 9.00% |
| Romania | Chamber of Deputies | 329 | 19 | 5.78% |
| Hungary | National Assembly | 199 | 10 | 5.03% |
| Lithuania | Seimas | 141 | 4 | 2.84% |
| Italy | Senate of the Republic | 321 | 9 | 2.80% |
| Czech Republic | Senate | 81 | 2 | 2.47% |
| France | National Assembly | 577 | 14 | 2.43% |
| Italy | Chamber of Deputies | 630 | 15 | 2.38% |
| Bulgaria | National Assembly | 240 | 5 | 2.08% |
| Cyprus | House of Representatives | 56 | 1 | 1.79% |
| France | Senate | 348 | 6 | 1.72% |
| Sweden | Riksdag | 116 | 2 | 1.72% |
| Slovenia | National Assembly | 90 | 1 | 1.11% |
| Poland | Senate | 100 | 1 | 1.00% |
| Estonia | Riigikogu | 101 | 1 | 0.99% |
| The Netherland | House of Representatives | 150 | 1 | 0.67% |
| Poland | Sejm | 460 | 3 | 0.65% |
| Germany | Bundestag | 709 | 4 | 0.56% |
| Austria | National Council | 183 | 1 | 0.55% |
| Portugal | Assembly of the Republic | 230 | 1 | 0.43% |
| Austria | Federal Council | 61 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Belgium | Chamber of Representatives | 150 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Belgium | Senate | 60 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Czech Republic | Chamber of Deputies | 200 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Denmark | Folketing | 179 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Finland | Parliament | 200 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Germany | Bundesrat | 69 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Greece | Parliament | 300 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Luxembourg | Chamber of Deputies | 60 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Malta | Parliament | 67 | 0 | 0.00% |
| The Netherland | Senate | 75 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Slovakia | National Council | 150 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Spain | Congress of Deputies | 350 | 0 | 0.00% |
| Spain | Senate | 265 | 0 | 0.00% |

Comment: While this answers the question, I wonder if it shouldn't also take into account whether the voting system discourages independents from running (or winning) as in the De Hondt system. If one or two independents made it in from a system where independents should, by design, be excluded, it's more relevant than independents making it into the house in a system where independents are favoured or treated neutrally compared to parties.

Comment: In some of these chambers, the only practical way to become an independent member is to leave the party (or being expelled by the party) while holding a seat.

Comment: I think you should also exclude the Bundesrat. Its members aren't elected but appointed by the state governments with an imperative mandate. Even if they had no party affiliation, they would still be dependent on their state government.